# How to get a product by Id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to display **product details** from `sales_order_item`. How can we display information about the product according to its id?
I have this page: 
[image]
code for this page, I have: 
[image]
When we click on *Order Detail*, it will just get that's one and display data to a new page (***Page_Detail***).

I have this file in *Module\Block\Display.php*
[image]

And in file .phtml:

[image]

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` get Order Information

```
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
          ...
          \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
          ....
    ) {
          ....
          $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
          ....
     }
    public function getOrder()
    {
       $orderId = 105105; //order id
       $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId); //get Order 
       foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {  //get All product of order
         // var_dump($item->getData());
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Rk Rathod, i have updated my question.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: thanks for answered, I have tried and get this error : Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::$orderRepository in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php on line 110

Comment: after this code try to setup:upgrade command and cache clean check

Comment: I did, and still get that error

Comment: please attach your code

Comment: add code in block file and call block in phtml file

Comment: I have tried. Still get that eror

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    ....
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $orderId = 105105;
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    $item_name = [];
    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        //var_dump($item->getData());
        $item_name[] = $item->getName()."<br/>";
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Now, call function in your phtml file :

```
$item_name = $block->yourFunction();
print_r($item_name);
```

Execute this command and check it :

- rm -rf generated/*
- php bin/magento c:c

Comment: Hi Rohan, I have tried and get the error : The entity that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the entity and try again.

Comment: It seems like this order id not available in table.

Comment: Please check record in sales_order table. Find this id if record not exist it means record not available in order history.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. But seem not my request

Comment: You can accept with upvote answer :) So, it will helpful for other also and if you have query. Then, you can feel free to ask :)

Comment: Could you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95666/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-user81098).

Answer (score 0):

You can do using object manager also like below:

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use Repository pattern in order to get the product details.
If you want to get product details by id, first add the object via DI

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
 */
private $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

And use the `productRepository` object to get details by `$productId` as:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
var_dump($product->getData());
```